# How to store values of attributes of different type as EAV?

Tags: database-design, entity-attribute-value

Could you tell please how to store values of attributes of different type as EAV?

I see 3 options now.

1. To store in one tables in different fields something like:
   entity_id attribute_id string_value numberic_value date_value.
2. To store values of different type of attributes in different tables, for example string_attribute_values, numeric_attribute_values, date_attribute_values.
3. To store values of all types as VARCHAR, but this variant seem inapropriate because it's hard to make filtering for example, by numeric value (they'll be compare as strings) and it let's for example to input letter in the fields where only digits should be.

I suppose I need now: string, numberic (integer) and date type but maybe other types appear later.

Thank you.

Comment: Option 3 will also give you problems when it comes to sorting, not to mention the performance hit of having to convert from varchar to the  proper type for each value.  We're attempting our first EAV design and we're going with option 2

Comment: I also try to go with option 2.

Answer (score 1):

In the RDBMS community, EAV is an antipattern. For the "inifinite flexibility" gained by using EAV, the SQL required to reconstitute the data as records/objects is significantly more complex. You also get the "benefit" of not being able to use any of the data integrity tools available to you (foreign keys, check constraints, etc.) Over time, this design collapses under its own weight.

If you have a use case where the data elements are part of super-type/sub-type relationships, but they don't change much, then model tables according to your needs:

1.) Class Table Inheritance = specific sub-type tables with a common parent. This is best when the super-type and sub-types each have a significant number of unique attributes.

2.) Concrete Table Inheritance = place the common super-type columns in each sub-type's table. This works better when the super-type does not have many of its own attributes, but the sub-types do.

3.) Single Table Inheritance = place the columns for all sub-types in 1 table along with the super-type's columns. Columns that do not pertain to a particular row's sub-type have a NULL value. This works best for when each sub-type does not have many unique attributes or multiple sub-types share columns/attributes.

You can mix and match those 3 a little, but I would suggest sticking with one of those designs.

If you really need to use EAV, you use XML columns in an RDBMS if a relatively small proportion of your data is in your EAV design (compared to the overall database). If a lot of your data would be stored in an EAV, then a RDBMS is not the tool you need. Look into the document/NoSQL/Key-Value databases like MongoDB, Cassandra, etc. RDBMSes that implement EAV, if not early on, eventually become a coding nightmare.

Given the date of your question, I'd be curious to know which route you chose and what you learned, what you liked/didn't like, etc.

Comment: Class table,contrete table and single table inheritance are not applicable in my case. Using XML is antipattern too (even there is 1 NF, there are problems with data integrity and search). Now I try to use EAV in this system for small part of it. For storing values of EAV is use different tables for different types: for strings, dates, numbers. Of course EAV causes some difficutlies too but frankly speaking I don't see an alternative right now. I looket a mongodb, couchdb and didn't find it could help me very much in my case.

Comment: I appreciate your concerns. The more limited the use of EAV in an RDBMS, the better off you are in the long term. The key is to enter into it with your eyes wide open. Also check out some of the posts in the related list to the right of this page. Lots of opinions out there.